# Normal closures of finite dimensional field extensions (existence, uniqueness, example)

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

The definition I have for a normal closure is $E \subset G$ is a normal closure if any normal extension of $F$ containing $E$ contains a subfield F-isomorphic to $G$

**Existence:**  Take$G$ to be the intersection of all normal extensions of $E$ (already proved there exists at least one) then this will be a normal extension and obviously there will be a subgroup that is F-isomorphic to $G$ since $G$ is contained in every normal extension.  Am I missing any details?

**Uniqueness (up to isomorphism):** Here is where I am struggling.  I assume uniqueness follows somehow from the uniqueness of a splitting field, but it may also be necessary to suppose that there are 2 and take an element the is in one and not the other and arrive at a contradiction somehow, but I don't see how.

**Example:** $F = \mathbb{Q},E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2), G$ a normal closure of $E \supset F$.  Describe Gal($G/F$).  $[E:F] = 3$ because {$1, \sqrt[3]2, \sqrt[3]2^2$} forms a basis.  So the normal closure would be the splitting field.  Is that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2, \sqrt[3]4)$?  I'm having trouble finding it.  Then do I just find [G:F] and then find a group of that order and that is isomorphic to the Galois group

Comment: FYI There are infinitely many rational numbers, so the tag [tag:finite-fields] was not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Existence:** Looks pretty good.

**Uniqueness:** Suppose there are two, $G_1$ and $G_2$. You don't need to consider elements in one and not the other and derive a contradiction; an easier path would be to try to prove $G_1$ contains $G_2$ and vice versa, so they must be equal. Can you do this from the definition of normal closure?

**Example:** Since $\sqrt[3]{4} = \sqrt[3]{2}^2$, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[3]4)$ is just the same as $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$. So it can't be the normal closure unless $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ is already normal over $\mathbb Q$. Is it? If not, why not? This will help you find the normal closure.

Comment: its not a splitting field because the minimal polynomial $x^3 - 2$ doesn't split in it since not all of its roots ( $\sqrt[3]-2, -\sqrt[3]{-2}$) are contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2)$?  So we can adjoin $i\sqrt[3]{2}$ to obtain the splitting field? Then the size of this extension is 2 so the Galois group is isomorphic to $S_2$?

Comment: Or wait we want $Gal(G/F)$ so that would have order $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2, i\sqrt[3]2): \mathbb{Q}] = 4$ so it would be isomorphic to $K_4$?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I think its actually 6 since $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2):\mathbb{Q}] = 3$ as shown above so its either $\mathbb{Z}_6$ or $S_3$. How do I know which?

Comment: @user558377 (Sorry for the late response.) Not quite $i\sqrt[3]2$ -- $\omega\sqrt[3]2$, where $\omega$ is a complex cube root of $1$. The order is $6$. To distinguish between $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $S_3$, you have to think about what the automorphisms are and compare them to the groups at hand. It's often helpful to think about the action of automorphisms on the roots of a polynomial. Here, any automorphism must permute the three roots of $x^3-2$, and such a permutation determines the automorphism exactly, so the Galois group must be a subgroup of $S_3$.